# PubNub - Decrypt error when random initialization vector is used on client-side

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes, pubnub

When on our JavaScript node back-end, the `useRandomIVs` option is true, on our mobile app using the latest PubNub Objective-c 4.17.0 with also useRandomInitializationVector true are receiving the “Decrypt error” error.

When setting `useRandomInitializationVector` on mobile to false (with no changed back-end `useRandomIVs` on true), decryption works on mobile.

What can be the problem? Why is PubNub not successfully decrypting when `useRandomInitializationVector` is true on the mobile side?

Comment: Please submit these details with your sub-key and enable SDK logging on both ends and submit to support@pubnub.com along with a link to this post.

Comment: https://support.pubnub.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057750412-Encryption-not-working-after-SDK-update